# how to prevent fetch from redirecting to another view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fetch

I have a very simple fetch function along with controller action. It works well, however it redirects me to the form action URL !!!  I need just to get a message to show with no need to redirect to another view.

HTML form

```
<form id="subscribtionFrm" asp-action="Subscribe" asp-controller="Home">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama" asp-for="subscriber.Name">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" asp-for="subscriber.Email">
    </div>
    <button onclick="SubmitSubscriber()" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

JS fetch

```
function SubmitSubscriber() {

    var frm = document.forms["subscribtionFrm"];
    var Url = frm.action;
    console.log(frm);
    console.log(Url);

    fetch(frm)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Something went wrong !! from JS catch.', error));

    return false;
};
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubscribeAsync(Subscriber subscriber)
{
    subscriber.id = Guid.NewGuid();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Subscriber GetEmail = context.subscribers.Where(e => e.Email == subscriber.Email).FirstOrDefault();
        if (GetEmail != null)
        {
            return Json("This Email is already Subscriped !");
        }
        else
        {
            subscriber.id = Guid.NewGuid();
            context.Add(subscriber);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json("You have Subscribed successfully");
        }
    }
    return Json("Something went wrong !");
}
```

rather than getting just JSON result, I get the result plus redirecting to the form action URL

**https://localhost:00000/Home/Subscribe**

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for redirect is you submitted the form itself rather than form data. here is my model answer with submitting your form data instead.

HTML

```
<form id="subscribtionFrm" onsubmit="SubmitSubscriber()" asp-action="Subscribe" asp-controller="Home" novalidate>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama" asp-for="subscriber.Name">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" asp-for="subscriber.Email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
var SubmitSubscriber = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //var frm = document.forms["subscribtionFrm"];
    var frm = this.event.target;
    var Url = frm.action;
    var frmData = new FormData(this.event.target);
    console.log(frm);
    console.log(Url);

    fetch(Url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: frmData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => alert(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Something went wrong !! from JS catch.', error));
    return false;
}
```